# Ubuntu gnome 16.04 xenial xerus - Changing Automatic Brightness Response Time

Tags: brightness, 16.04, automatic

I am using Ubuntu gnome 16.04 LTS version.

I love automatic brightness feature but it is getting changed so quickly, so responsive, so fast response, it is so annoying.

How can I change the response time to different light levels?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried wildguppy? see http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/wildguppy-adjusts-your-laptops.html. it has features you are looking for (sample response time etc)

Comment: thank you but my laptop has built in brightness sensor. in windows 10 i am using this feature properly. i think gnome's new auto brightness feature is also using built in sensors. actually i dont like autobrightness by using front camera.  if i am wrong, please correct me.

Comment: try this https://github.com/hadess/iio-sensor-proxy and see if it stabilises sensor. also see https://developer.gnome.org/iio-sensor-proxy/

Comment: No, it is still same.

Comment: wildguppy will not install (without forcing) on 16.04 xenial. It gives the error message after adding the PPA and updating apt: `E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/fantasyleague0629/wildguppy/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.`

Answer (score 0):

It is a very old program. His maintainer did not updated it since 2 years ago. 
For Ubuntu Xenial the best way to install it is through the `.deb` file.

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~fantasyleague0629/+archive/ubuntu/wildguppy/+files/wildguppy_1.0.3-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i wildguppy_1.0.3-1_all.deb
```