# How do I disable Automatic Brightness in Ubuntu-Gnome [16.04/15.10]?

Tags: gnome, 16.04, brightness, ubuntu-gnome, automatic

Before someone points me to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762577/ubuntu-gnome-16-04-xenial-xerus-changing-automatic-brightness-response-time) I would like to point out that I want to **completely disable** the auto-brightness change feature as it doesn't work at all for me, and I am not interested in **any** auto-brightness apps.

Plain GNOME as such has an option for disabling this feature in the **Power Options** but ubuntu-gnome unfortunately didn't inherit it.

I can't leave Ubuntu and I don't want to switch out of GNOME. If it comes to that, I might well have to install GNOME on top of some other Ubuntu flavour(?) and try :/

- OS - Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 as well as 15.10
- GNOME - 3.18.2/3/4; Didn't work on any of them.
- Kernel - 4.4.0-22-generic

Comment: Can someone update this to 20.04? I run it in a VM on a Windows 10 host and it's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 14):

I realize this is a bit late but I was googling for this solution and I found the setting when I was messing around. Settings > power then turn automatic brightness off ! Hope it helps.

Comment: This has been driving me crazy since switching from Unity. Why on earth is it in power, not screen? At least stick a line of text somewhere telling me I'm looking in the wrong place

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu 16.04, if you go to All Settings > Brightness & Lock, there is an "Dim screen to save power" checkbox. Uncheck this option and the computer should stop attempting to change the brightness automatic. There is also an option on the same page right above this checkbox to manually set the brightness. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 20.10 it is

> Settings -> Power -> Power Saving -> Automatic Brightness